# Yii2: how to display an attribute in view outside GridView

Tags: gridview, attributes, yii2

I know in GridView one can display an attribute just by naming it inside *columns*:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'emptyCell' => '-',
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'myAttribute',
        'myRelation.myRelatedAttribute',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

But is there such a straightforward way of doing it right outside GridView not resorting to class methods? For instance, in the view headings rather than title:

```
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of models like this :

```
$dataProvider->models;
```

So if you want to get the title of the first model in the list :

```
<h1><?= !empty($dataProvider->models) ? $dataProvider->models[0]->title : '' ?></h1>
```